# How to upload a file using Gin + React?

Tags: reactjs, go, go-gin

I want to upload a image file from React, doing so seems I need to store the image on the server and retrieve it from a POST request in order to modify it into a url path.

- Using Gin Gonic http framework.

Here is the form in  React for my POST request:

```
    <form action="/upload" method="POST">
      <label htmlFor="upload" onChange={onChange}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserCircle} color="#3B5998" size="10x" className={`${pointer}`} />
        <input type="file" hidden id="upload" name="upload" />
      </label>
    </form>
```

Here is my method I am calling in an `onChange` to send the request along with the image file:

```
  uploadFile = (file) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${gamingApiBaseURL}/v1/upload-image`,
      data: formData,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error storing image', error);
    });
  };
```

Here is my Go struct in order to bind the request

```
type ImageForm struct {
    Image *multipart.FileHeader `form:"upload binding:"required"`
}
```

Lastly, the method that is supposed to get the image file and upload it to the server. Here is what I have so far. I am receiving an error saying `http: no such file` which is weird because in Postman I see the `image` key and the filename, I'm trying to make sense of how uploading an image works in Go.

```
func extractImage(c *gin.Context) {
    // Using 'ShouldBind'
    formFile, err := c.FormFile("image")

    fmt.Println("Error", err)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    }

    fmt.Println("form error", formFile)
}
```

Comment: I think the problem Im facing is on the React side, transforming the form data correctly to retrieve the file correctly. Works in Postman.

Comment: Remove `{ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }`.

Comment: I still receive a no such file when I upland a png/jpg image from my file system.

Comment: @mjubilee1 Haven't you found a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I think this struct tag is wrong

```golang
type ImageForm struct {
    Image *multipart.FileHeader `form:"upload binding:"required"`
}
```

Change to this (missing double quote after `upload`):

```golang
type ImageForm struct {
    Image *multipart.FileHeader `form:"upload" binding:"required"`
}
```